# Jump to the previous window when closing the current

Tags: emacs, window

I have few problems with the focus jump after closing the current window in multiple-window situation. E.g. I have 3 windows (1, 2, 3) opened in the stack. I am in window 2, I horizontally split the current window (there are 1,2,3,4 windows and current is 3), I quit he window and the cursor jumps to window 3. It feels quite unintuitive. How can I make that in this scenario the focus gets to window 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following function:

```elisp
(defun delete-window-select-sibling (&optional WINDOW)
  (interactive)
  (let ((sibling (or (window-prev-sibling WINDOW)
                     (window-next-sibling WINDOW))))
    (delete-window WINDOW)
    (when sibling
      (select-window sibling))))
```

You can bind it to <kbd>C-x 0</kbd> by putting it into your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) together with the following line:

```elisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x 0") 'delete-window-select-sibling)
```

In my opinion, a small auxiliary function like the above is preferable to [advising](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) `delete-window` because some modes might rely on how the latter works.

Comment: It does not work for the case where I have 4 windows and current is 4th. When I jump to 3rd and close it 2nd get focused instead of 3rd. Can you help, please, with this situation?

Comment: Can you please describe how you get to the 4 windows starting from a single window (i.e. the sequence of splits you perform)?

Comment: Yes, just split 4 times. IRL, that would split work on some windows, split, etc. and just end up with 4 windows and in the 4th one, i.e. the route of achieving the situation can be kind of unpredictable.

Comment: The following works for me: start Emacs; then type: `C-x 2`, `C-x 2`, `C-x 2` (now there are four windows) `C-x o`, `C-x o`, `C-x o` (now point is in window #4), `M-x delete-window-select-sibling` (window #4 disappears, point is in window #3).

Comment: After you point in in window #4, you move to window #3 (without closing window #4), then you close window #3 and I expect you to be in window #3 out of 3 windows.

Comment: When I do as you describe, the space occupied by window #3 is given to window #2 when window #3 is closed. It does not seem unnatural to me that, hence, point also goes to window #2?